# Прикрепить изображение к статусу - VIP объявление

Tags: изображения, php

Уважаемые знатоки!
У меня фон появляется при присвоении статуса ВИП - объявления.
Хочу сделать так, чтобы вместе с фоном появлялось изображение(иконка вип).
Как правильно это сделать?
Ниже код выделения цветом...

```
do 
        { 
        if (isset ($row_Recordset1['id'])) 
            {
            if($row_Recordset1['vip']) $vip_fon='bgcolor="#fffbd1"'; else $vip_fon=''; /////////////////// VIP FON
```

Answer (score 1):

А решение не имеет отношения к php. В php вы можете только присвоить переменной какую то картинку или класс для последующего использования в html.

А вообще это html+css

Почитайте еще вот [это](http://programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=41149)
Почитайте еще и вот [это](http://www.php.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=13154)

Сравните и выясните ЧТО вам надо сделать....

Comment: @thunder условие имеет отношение к php, а то что у ТС неправильный подход к реализации, это уже другое дело!

Comment: условие поставлено не верно в конечном итоге. мы не знам как он фон меняет, где, в чем...

пока что ответ на вопрос

        if($row_Recordset1['vip']) { $vip_fon='bgcolor="#fffbd1"'; $vip_pic='my_cool_vip_picture.jpg'; } else { $vip_fon=''; $vip_pic=''; }